# Get attributes of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

i want to get these value "xxxxx" from the  element "src" from these div

i tried so many getelements but it didn't work.

can anybody help me in that

```
<div id="iframe_container" >
    <iframe name="I1" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" align="center" src="xxxxx"  class="floating_iframe"> 
        Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is to get the `src` of the iframe, you can use this code:

```
var iframes = document.getElementById("iframe_container").getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var src = iframes[0].src;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can write:

```
var src = $('#iframe_container iframe').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Get the element - in this case iframe  (you can use `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByName` or any of other ways - depends if you're using any frameworks and what markup you have)
2. once you have the element you can simply call `getAttribute("src")` on that elemnt.

Example ( http://jsfiddle.net/K3pEw/12/ ):

```
var iFrame = document.getElementsByName('I1');
alert("The src attribute of your iframe is: "  + iFrame[0].getAttribute('src'))
```